# why am I getting NaN in my neural network sometimes?

Tags: java, neural-network, backpropagation, feed-forward

I recently wrote a neural network using a series of videos in youtube, the channel was coding train. It was written in js I wrote mine in java. It is working correct sometimes but other times I'm getting NaN as outputs and I can's figure out why?

Can anyone help? There is a Matrix class for some matrix math and neural network class it self with a test problem. First output is 1 if 0's are more than 1's and second one is 1 if else.

edit:
I found where the problem is but i still can't figure out why it happens?!
in happens in my static dot product method in Matrix class. sometimes one or both matrices data are NaN!

edit 2:
I checked, inputs are valid in constructor but in feedForward method they are NaN sometimes!!! could it be because I'm using a 10 years old laptop?! because the code doesn't seem to have any problem.

**solved:** I found the problem! in feedforward I didn't map sigmoid for output Matrix -_-

```
public class NeuralNetwork {

//private int inputNodes, hiddenNodes, outputNodes;
private Matrix weightsIH, weightsHO, biasH, biasO;
private double learningRate = 0.1;

public NeuralNetwork(int inputNodes, int hiddenNodes, int outputNodes) {
    //this.inputNodes = inputNodes;
    //this.hiddenNodes = hiddenNodes;
    //this.outputNodes = outputNodes;

    weightsIH = new Matrix(hiddenNodes, inputNodes);
    weightsHO = new Matrix(outputNodes, hiddenNodes);
    weightsIH.randomize();
    weightsHO.randomize();

    biasH = new Matrix(hiddenNodes, 1);
    biasO = new Matrix(outputNodes, 1);

    biasH.randomize();
    biasO.randomize();
}

public void setLearningRate(double learningRate) {
    this.learningRate = learningRate;
}

public double sigmoid(double x) {
    return 1 / (1 + Math.exp(-x));
}

public double dsigmoid(double y) {
    return y * (1 - y);
}

public double[] feedForward(double[] inputArray) throws Exception {

    Matrix inputs = Matrix.fromArray(inputArray);
    Matrix hidden = Matrix.dot(weightsIH, inputs);
    hidden.add(biasH);

    hidden.map(f -> sigmoid(f));

    Matrix output = Matrix.dot(weightsHO, hidden);
    output.add(biasO);

    return output.toArray();
}

public void train(double[] inputArray, double[] targetsArray) throws Exception {

    Matrix targets = Matrix.fromArray(targetsArray);

    // feed forward algorithm //
    Matrix inputs = Matrix.fromArray(inputArray);
    Matrix hidden = Matrix.dot(weightsIH, inputs);
    hidden.add(biasH);

    hidden.map(f -> sigmoid(f));

    Matrix outputs = Matrix.dot(weightsHO, hidden);
    outputs.add(biasO);
    // feed forward algorithm //

    // Calculate outputs ERRORS
    Matrix outputErrors = Matrix.subtract(targets, outputs);

    // Calculate outputs Gradients
    Matrix outputsGradients = Matrix.map(outputs, f -> dsigmoid(f));
    outputsGradients.multiply(outputErrors);
    outputsGradients.multiply(learningRate);

    // Calculate outputs Deltas
    Matrix hidden_t = Matrix.transpose(hidden);
    Matrix weightsHO_deltas = Matrix.dot(outputsGradients, hidden_t);

    // adjust outputs weights
    weightsHO.add(weightsHO_deltas);
    // adjust outputs bias
    biasO.add(outputsGradients);

    // Calculate hidden layer ERRORS
    Matrix weightsHO_t = Matrix.transpose(weightsHO);
    Matrix hiddenErrors = Matrix.dot(weightsHO_t, outputErrors);

    // Calculate hidden Gradients
    Matrix hiddenGradients = Matrix.map(hidden, f -> dsigmoid(f));
    hiddenGradients.multiply(hiddenErrors);
    hiddenGradients.multiply(learningRate);

    // Calculate hidden Deltas
    Matrix inputs_t = Matrix.transpose(inputs);
    Matrix weightsIH_deltas = Matrix.dot(hiddenGradients, inputs_t);

    // adjust hidden weights
    weightsIH.add(weightsIH_deltas);
    // adjust hidden bias
    biasH.add(hiddenGradients);

}

public static void print(double[] data) {
    for (double d : data) {
        System.out.print(d + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    NeuralNetwork nn = new NeuralNetwork(3, 4, 2);
    double[][] trainingInputs = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}};
    double[][] targets = {{1, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}};

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < trainingInputs.length; j++) {
            try {
                nn.train(trainingInputs[j], targets[j]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    double[] output;

    try {
        output = nn.feedForward(new double[]{0, 0, 0});
        print(output);
        output = nn.feedForward(new double[]{0, 0, 1});
        print(output);
        output = nn.feedForward(new double[]{0, 1, 0});
        print(output);
        output = nn.feedForward(new double[]{0, 1, 1});
        print(output);
        output = nn.feedForward(new double[]{1, 0, 0});
        print(output);
        output = nn.feedForward(new double[]{1, 0, 1});
        print(output);
        output = nn.feedForward(new double[]{1, 1, 0});
        print(output);
        output = nn.feedForward(new double[]{1, 1, 1});
        print(output);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} }


public class Matrix {

public double[][] data;

public Matrix(int row, int col) {
    data = new double[row][col];
}

public Matrix(double[][] data) {

    this.data = data;
}

public void randomize() {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++) {
            data[i][j] = new Random().nextDouble() * 2 - 1;
        }
    }
}

public Matrix transpose() {
    Matrix result = new Matrix(data[0].length, data.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++) {
            result.data[j][i] = data[i][j];
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public static Matrix transpose(Matrix m) {
    Matrix result = new Matrix(m.data[0].length, m.data.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < m.data.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m.data[0].length; j++) {
            result.data[j][i] = m.data[i][j];
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public void add(double n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++) {
            data[i][j] += n;
        }
    }
}

public void subtract(double n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++) {
            data[i][j] -= n;
        }
    }
}

public void add(Matrix m) throws Exception {
    if (!(data.length == m.data.length && data[0].length == m.data[0].length)) 
        throw new Exception("columns and rows don't match!");

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++) {
            data[i][j] += m.data[i][j];
        }
    }
}

public void subtract(Matrix m) throws Exception {
    if (!(data.length == m.data.length && data[0].length == m.data[0].length))
        throw new Exception("columns and rows don't match!");

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++) {
            data[i][j] -= m.data[i][j];
        }
    }
}

public static Matrix add(Matrix m1, Matrix m2) throws Exception {
    if (!(m1.data.length == m2.data.length && m1.data[0].length == m2.data[0].length)) 
        throw new Exception("columns and rows don't match!");

    Matrix result = new Matrix(m1.data.length, m1.data[0].length);

    for (int i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < result.data[0].length; j++) {
            result.data[i][j] = m1.data[i][j] + m2.data[i][j];
        }
    }

    return result;
}

public static Matrix subtract(Matrix m1, Matrix m2) throws Exception {
    if (!(m1.data.length == m2.data.length && m1.data[0].length == m2.data[0].length)) 
        throw new Exception("columns and rows don't match!");

    Matrix result = new Matrix(m1.data.length, m1.data[0].length);

    for (int i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < result.data[0].length; j++) {
            result.data[i][j] = m1.data[i][j] - m2.data[i][j];
        }
    }

    return result;
}

public void multiply(double n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++) {
            data[i][j] *= n;
        }
    }
}

public void multiply(Matrix m) throws Exception {
    if (!(data.length == m.data.length && data[0].length == m.data[0].length)) 
        throw new Exception("columns and rows don't match!");

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++) {
            data[i][j] *= m.data[i][j];
        }
    }
}

public static Matrix multiply(Matrix m1, Matrix m2) throws Exception {
    if (!(m1.data.length == m2.data.length && m1.data[0].length == m2.data[0].length)) 
        throw new Exception("columns and rows don't match!");

    Matrix result = new Matrix(m1.data.length, m1.data[0].length);
    for (int i = 0; i < m1.data.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m1.data[0].length; j++) {
            result.data[i][j] = m1.data[i][j] * m2.data[i][j];
        }
    }

    return result;
}

public Matrix dot(Matrix m) throws Exception {
    if (data[0].length != m.data.length) 
        throw new Exception("columns and rows don't match!");

    Matrix result = new Matrix(data.length, m.data[0].length);

    for (int i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < result.data[0].length; j++) {
            double sum = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < data[0].length; k++) {
                sum += data[i][k] * m.data[k][j];
            }
            result.data[i][j] = sum;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

public static Matrix dot(Matrix m1, Matrix m2) throws Exception {
    if (m1.data[0].length != m2.data.length) 
        throw new Exception("columns and rows don't match!");

    Matrix result = new Matrix(m1.data.length, m2.data[0].length);

    for (int i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < result.data[0].length; j++) {
            double sum = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < m1.data[0].length; k++) {
                sum += m1.data[i][k] * m2.data[k][j];
            }
            result.data[i][j] = sum;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

public static interface Func {

    public double method(double d);
}

public void map(Func f) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++) {
            data[i][j] = f.method(data[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

public static Matrix map(Matrix m, Func f) {
    Matrix result = new Matrix(m.data.length, m.data[0].length);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < m.data.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m.data[0].length; j++) {
            result.data[i][j] = f.method(m.data[i][j]);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

public static Matrix fromArray(double[] arr) {

    Matrix res = new Matrix(arr.length, 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        res.data[i][0] = arr[i];
    }
    return res;
}

public double[] toArray() {
    double[] res = new double[data.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        res[i] = data[i][0];
    }

    return res;
}

public void print() {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(data[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options for debugging this, and they can even be used together.

### Add debug output

Add debug output for all of your calculations so you can see what exactly is causing the unexpected value. For example, you have...

```
public double sigmoid(double x) {
    return 1 / (1 + Math.exp(-x));
}
```

but you could see what that is doing by making it...

```
public double sigmoid(double x) {
    double sigmoid = 1 / (1 + Math.exp(-x));
    System.out.println("1 / (1 + Math.exp(" + (-x) + ")) = " + sigmoid);
    return sigmoid;
}
```

Do that anywhere you perform a calculation which could result in your unexpected value.

I suggest you output some debug info like this, then search the contents of the output for NaN. This would be even easier if you can get the output into a file and then open that file in a word processor to do a text search - if you're running on the command line you could do `java MyApp > myapp_log.txt` then open `myapp_log.txt` in a text editor to do a text search.

Or to make the output easier to handle, you could make your debug logic only output when it finds NaN, such as...

```
public double sigmoid(double x) {
    double sigmoid = 1 / (1 + Math.exp(-x));
    if(sigmoid == Double.NaN)
        System.out.println("1 / (1 + Math.exp(" + (-x) + ")) = " + sigmoid);
    return sigmoid;
}
```

Just remember to do it for everything you calculate, including your `dsigmoid`, your `add`, etc., everywhere you have any type of calculation. If you put enough of it everywhere then you will catch the problem and see lines output like "1 / (1 + Math.exp(NaN)) = NaN".

### Use a debugger

There are various things you can do with a debugger. You can run your program but step through it one line at a time and examine every variable and result as it is happening. Depending on the size of your matrices and how many times these functions get called, this may take a lot of effort.

Or you might be able to set a "watch" on a variable to have the program halt when a certain value equals NaN, then inspect the state of the program at that moment - I'm not sure if any debuggers for Java have this functionality though, as I've only done this type of debugging in C or assembly so you'd have to figure out if you have access to such a debugger.

Comment: That is a very nice technique thanks, and looks like what is going in the sigmoid function is a NaN actually!